# Django Jquery Login Form

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, django-forms

I created a login form that sits inside a dialogbox. It works as expected without any ajax. The issue is that I would like to validate the login form prior to closing the dialogbox. Right now, if someone clicks submit, the dialog box closes. On successful login its fine, however if there is an error, the user needs to click login again for the error to find out that something is wrong. Therefore I am trying to implement jquery to validate the data prior to closing the dialog box.

**Template**

```
     <a id="login_div" onclick="toggleOverlay();" stlye="color:blue; cursor:pointer;">login or register</a>                                  
76        <div class="overlay">                                                                                                                
77            <div class="wrap-outer">                                                                                                         
78                <div class="wrap">                                                                                                           
79                    <div class="my-dialog">                                                                                                  
80                <a style="color:blue; cursor:pointer;" onclick="toggleOverlay();">Close</a>                                                  
81                                                                                                                                             
82                <form id="login_form" name="login_form" action="" method="post">                                                             
83                                                                                                                                             
84                                                                                                                                             
85                    <h3 id="login_header">Login</h3>                                                                                         
86                                                                                                                                             
87                    <label id="login_username">Username:</label>                                                                             
88                    <label id="login_form_username">{{ request.login_form.username }}< /label>                                                
89                    <label id="login_password" for="password">Password:</label>                                                              
90                    <label id="login_form_password">{{ request.login_form.password }} </label>                                                
91                                                                                                                                             
92                     {% csrf_token %}                                                                                                        
93                                                                                                                                             
94                    <input id="login_button" type="submit" name="login_name" value="login" />                                                
95                    <input type="hidden" id="request_path" name="next" value="{{ request.path }}"/>                                          
96                                                                                                                                             
97                </form>
```

**jquery**

```
1 $(window).load(function(){                                                                                                                  
2 $('#login_form').submit(function(e){                                                                                                        
3  var request_url = document.getElementById('#request_path')                                                                                 
4          $.ajax({                                                                                                                           
5             type:"POST",                                                                                                                    
6             url: request_url,                                                                                                               
7             data:$('#register_form').serialize(),                                                                                           
8             error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){ alert(thrownError); },                                                          
9             success: function(data){}                                                                                                       
10             });                                                                                                                             
11      e.preventDefault();                                                                                                                    
12 });                                                                                                                                         
13 });
```

**View**

```
13     def process_request(self, request):                                                                                                     
14                                                                                                                                             
15         # if the top login form has been posted                                                                                             
16         if request.method == 'POST':                                                                                                        
17                                                                                                                                             
18             # validate the form                                                                                                             
19             lform = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)                                                                                   
20             if lform.is_valid():                                                                                                            
21                                                                                                                                             
22                 # log the user in                                                                                                           
23                 django_login(request, lform.get_user())                                                                                     
24                 return HttpResponseRedirect(request.REQUEST.get('next', '/'))                                                               
25                                                                                                                                             
26                                                                                                                                             
27                 # if this is the logout page, then redirect to /                                                                            
28                 # so we don't get logged out just after logging in                                                                          
29             else:                                                                                                                           
30                 lform                                                                                                                       
31                                                                                                                                             
32         else:                                                                                                                               
33             lform = AuthenticationForm(request)                                                                                             
34                                                                                                                                             
35         # attach the form to the request so it can be accessed within the templates                                                         
36         request.login_form = lform
```

TL;DR: I would like to validate a login form using jquery and close the dialog box upon successful validation.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply leverage the built-in Django login view and return any validation errors as JSON which you can then display using jQuery?

You'll need to do a couple of things...

Inherit from the built-in AuthenticationForm and provide a method to return the form errors as JSON.
Check to see if there are any errors in the JSON, and iterate over them and adding them to the HTML inside the dialog.

[Shameless plug]
Please have a look at my AjaxForm/ModelForm base class, which will give you an extra method on the form called "errors_as_json". I also have some sample jQuery code to demonstrate how to display the errors.

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2393/

Happy coding.

Comment: +1 thats such an amazing solution. I had no idea this was possible. I dont understand this bit in your code though `if (errors.__all__ !== undefined) {
        form.append(errors.__all__);
    }`

Comment: Thank you. It's looking to see if there are any non-field errors, and if so, it appends them to the form.